# Get the new updated COOKIE value via AJAX using PHP

Tags: php, ajax, cookies

This is probably a newbie question, but i really need help.

I am creating a wishlist in an online store, and if the user is logged in, the wishlist item is going to be saved in the database and non logged in user's wishlist will be saved via cookies and I am using AJAX for the wishlist functionality. Everything goes well except that the cookies are not updated in the first ajax request.

This is my first steps(ajax):

1. call ajax request to update wishlist
2. reload wishlist template based on the new cookie

the above steps doesnt update automatically the wishlist template `$_COOKIE[]` needs a page refresh.

This is my updated steps(ajax)

1. call ajax request to update wishlist
2. call another ajax request to reload wishlist template

the above code solves the problem, (the number 2 step is called to just refresh the `$_cookie` value.), but it takes two ajax requests to update the wishlist, which takes a little time to work. Im sure, this is not the best solution. I know this is a better solution for this.

Help pls :)

Thanks

Comment: Cookies are set by the browser in the first request, and sent along with every further request that hits the server. But is this the issue here? Why not have the PHP (that your AJAX request hits) return you the wishlist along with the cookie?

Comment: Yes, why 2 calls? you can just pass an extra param for retrieving wishlist template. Also, you can create a js array and store there the cookies/sessions retrieved from server, as long as your page isnt refreshed and test just these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies can be set by [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) alone. As you are using [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) I think you can handle [cookies](/questions/tagged/cookies) fine without any page refresh.

Here is the logic you should implement.

1. Send an Ajax request to your PHP page.
2. - if you are logged in, PHP saves the data in database and return a status value 1.
   - Otherwise PHP returns a status value of 0. Means you were not logged in and couldn't save it in Database.
   - While returning `0`, PHP can populate `$_COOKIE` superglobal. It'll set the cookies in browser when the request is finished.
3. On the callback event of your ajax request you check the status value. if its `0` just save the data in cookie. This cookie is available via `document.cookie`. This can be easily done by [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)

#### sample code using jQuery

```
// ajax.js
$.post("updatewishlist.php", 
{
    'wishlist_item':'wishlist_value'
},
function(json){
// callback function
    if(json.status==0){
        $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7 });
    }
});
```

Here I have used [jquery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

```
// updatewishlist.php
<?php
if(user_logged_in()){
// sanitize input here
// update database with $_POST['wishlist_item']
$status = 1;
}else{
// update the cookie
// manipulate $_COOKIE super global
$status = 0;
}

// echoing json

echo json_encode(array('status' => $status));

?>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy!, so it means id rather use javascript over php in retrieving the cookie even if im using AJAX? Coz i dont get the updated cookie value in my AJAX